# angular 2 question 'map does not exist on type observable"

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am going through a angular 2 tutorial on youtube and for some reason I am getting this error "map does not exist on type observable". I did some reading and saw I should add that last import line but didn't fully solve it. I saw something about piping but wasn't sure how to modify the code accordingly. Thanks.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class GithubgithubService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getUser(searchText): Observable < any > {
    const url = 'http://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + searchText;
    return this.http.get(url).map(
      res => {
        const data = res.json();
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpClient` instead. You won't need to `map` the response in the first place.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class GithubgithubService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUser(searchText): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'http://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + searchText;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }

}
```

Make sure to add `HttpClientModule` to the `imports` array of your AppModule first.